# Can a macro in Notepad++ contain keystrokes?

Tags: regex, macros, notepad++

If I am trying to create a column in a text file and populate that column with the same value which is found in a particular area of the text file, I can get Find/Replace with Regular Expression to successfully do this. Since the column will be right most, I find `\r` and replace with `,VALUE,\r` where the `VALUE` is pasted from a previous copy (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>) command.  The problem is that I can't make this work as a macro on other files because it records the value of the of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> instead of the keystroke command <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>.  Is there a way for the macro to emulate <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> instead of filling in a particular value?

Added info:
Every line in the file would need the pasted value.  The reason is because every line contains a product number and a quantity. By being able to paste the value which is found in one of the headers, I can then link the lines to the order that is represented by the pasted value. So one table will contain order number, date, etc, where as the other table will contain the details of the order, i.e., the items.

This is a sample file:

ITEMNAME,ITEMID,QTY STORE #578 PO 0076875422 04-01-2014,SHIPPED
BLUE FISH,98799,3
RED FISH,48573,10
YELLOW SNAIL,94582,2
GREEN LIZARD-MEDIUM,32451,12
BLACK TARANTULA,29879,909

After running the script in notepad++ this file will look like this:
ITEMNAME,ITEMID,QTY STORE #578 PO 0076875422 04-01-2014,SHIPPED,ORDER_NUMBER
BLUE FISH,98799,3,,0076875422
RED FISH,48573,10,,0076875422
YELLOW SNAIL,94582,2,,0076875422
GREEN LIZARD-MEDIUM,32451,12,,0076875422
BLACK TARANTULA,29879,909,,0076875422

The header containing QTY contains other data: number of store,number of order, and date of order.  The order number is always preceded by "PO " and it is always 10 digits long.  The macro needs to be able to find it in each file and then add it to the end of each line, but it needs to be preceded by a comma to allow for a null value in the SHIPPED column.  Of course, you'll also notice that a header was added to the header row called ORDER_NUMBER.

Where I was getting stuck was in being able to paste the value of the order number to the end of each line b/c in my current macro, it is only able to paste the value that is pasted at the time of recording, not the actual PO Number in the current file that is being worked on.  So I figured if I could somehow record the CTRL-V keystroke after telling the Macro to find the PO number in the header row and copy it to the clipboard, that then it would work.

Comment: The copy and paste shortcuts work _outside_ of the find/replace dialog just fine in macros. They do not, however, appear to work inside the dialog- This could be due to how the dialog is recorded compared to other commands given, but it's hard to say for sure. I found this line in the [Notepad++ Wiki](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Macros), which is what leads me to that idea: _"Notepad++ handles find and replace actions recording itself, as they would present the same difficulty."_ I'm currently looking for a way to do this, but it might just not be possible.

Comment: Hi Kendra.  If you discover anything, would be great to hear back.  I have been told a python script can accomplish what I was trying to accomplish but that Notepadd ++ cannot store the keystrokes as I had hoped.

Comment: I've yet to find a way to do it myself. I had hoped maybe a plugin would help, but nothing I've tried has. I think your best bet will be to go with the script. Maybe a future update will do it, but it looks like this just isn't quiet possible currently. (I've also looked at manually editing a saved macro, but I think something's up with my system that's causing it not to save correctly. If I _do_ manage to do this and get it to work, I'll post an answer on how to do it.)

Comment: @chano I think I can provide an nppexec script which can help you. Would you consider using nppexec (a notepad++ plugin available via the plugin-manager, and you can assign keyboard shortcuts to nppexec scripts)?  If yes, please add some more information, e.g. do you want to append the `,VALUE` to every line in the file or only to a certain subset (e.g. the lines with `VALUE`)? It would be best to add some example input lines together the required output lines.

Comment: Thanks, Lars, yes, would definitely use an nppexec script.  I will add some info to the post.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the promised NppExec script. Save it to a *script name*, then you can add it to the NppExec menu with a Menu *item name* (in the Plugins -> NppExec -> Advanced Options associate the *script name* to an *item name*), after a restart of notepad++ you will find this *item name* somewhere in the shortcut mapper (under the plugins tab) and you can assign a keyboard shortcut to it.

**npp_exec script**

```
// http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html
// http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Moving_And_Selecting_Around

NPP_CONSOLE OFF

// 1. retrieve to PO:
  // 1.1 set the first line as target for the search
  SCI_SENDMSG SCI_DOCUMENTSTART
  SCI_SENDMSG SCI_LINEDOWN

  SCI_SENDMSG SCI_GETCURRENTPOS
  set Line1End ~ $(MSG_RESULT) -1

  // 1.2 do a RE search for the PO and retrieve the value for later reuse
  // set the range for the RE search to the first line
  SCI_SENDMSG SCI_SETTARGETSTART 0
  SCI_SENDMSG SCI_SETTARGETEND $(Line1End)

  SCI_SENDMSG SCI_SETSEARCHFLAGS SCFIND_REGEXP
  SCI_SENDMSG SCI_SEARCHINTARGET 11 "PO (\d{10})"
  set POPos=$(MSG_RESULT)

  if $(POPos) == -1 goto NOTFOUND

  // 1.3 get the PO Text:
  SCI_SENDMSG SCI_GETTAG 1 @""
  set POText=$(MSG_LPARAM)

  // 2 append ",ORDER_NUMBER" to first line
  SCI_SENDMSG SCI_DOCUMENTSTART
  SCI_SENDMSG SCI_LINEEND
  SCI_SENDMSG SCI_INSERTTEXT -1 @",ORDER_NUMBER"

  // 3 append POText to every other line
  SCI_SENDMSG SCI_LINEDOWN
  :REPEAT
    // 3.1 append ",POText" to line
    SCI_SENDMSG SCI_LINEEND
    SCI_SENDMSG SCI_INSERTTEXT -1 @",$(POText)"

    // 3.2 as long as we have not reached the last line: loop  
    SCI_SENDMSG SCI_LINEEND
    SCI_SENDMSG SCI_GETCURRENTPOS
    set pos1 = $(MSG_RESULT) 

    SCI_SENDMSG SCI_LINEDOWN
    SCI_SENDMSG SCI_GETCURRENTPOS
    set pos2 = $(MSG_RESULT) 

    // if the linedown doesnot give another pos, we have reached the end
    if $(pos1) == $(pos2) goto END
    // else loop
    if 1==1 goto REPEAT

  :NOTFOUND
    NPP_CONSOLE ON
    echo "There is no PO in the first line!"

  :END
```

It uses mostly the `SCI_SENDMSG` command of NppExec to remote control the editor. The documentation of the messages is in the link in the first line. But there is also a big amount of trial and error.

Comment: @Chano That solution is not very fast: e.g. only a few lines per second. I fear that this problem is not well suited for notepad++. Do you have sed or awk available?

Comment: Thank you very much Lars and Chris. Will explore this as soon as I can!

Comment: Lars, this actually works! I just added a comma here:    SCI_SENDMSG SCI_INSERTTEXT -1 @",,$(POText)" so that it could create a blank column for the SHIPPED data.  Because  my longest files will be around 200 lines long, I think the speed will be tolerable.  2 questions:  Is there an easy way to make it not create rows at the end of the file if the file ends with blank lines? Also, can the same command be expanded to perform the same action on other strings that are found in the QTY header such as store number? I don't have sed or awk. Users will be on Windows machines.

Answer (score 1):

The following assumes that there is only one PO number in each file
and should work in Notepad++ version 6.4.3 onwards:

**Description**

```
1) Define a  macro `Save PO #` that  
    a) Finds and saves the PO # to the clipboard  
    b) Advances to the start of the following line  

2) Define a macro `Add PO #` that  
    a) Adds a comma to the end of a line then pastes the clipboard  
    b) Advances to the next line  

3) For each file  
    a) Run macro `Save PO #`  
    b) Run macro `Add PO #` to `end of file`
```

**Method**

1)  `Start recording`
    `Ctrl+Home`
    `Find` Find what: `PO`
    `Find Next` `Alt+F4`
    `Right` `Edit` `Begin/End Select`
    `Find` Find what: 
    `Find Next` `Alt+F4`
    `Left` `Edit` `Begin/End Select` `Ctrl+C` `End` `Right`
    `Stop recording`
    `Save current recorded macro`  Name: `Save PO #` `OK`

2)  `Start recording`
    `End` `,` `Ctrl+V` `Right`
    `Stop recording`
    `Save current recorded macro`  Name: `Add PO #` `OK`

3)  Open a file for editing
    `Macro` `Save PO #`
    `Run a Macro Multiple Times`
    Macro to run: `Add PO #` `Run until end of file` `Run`

Comment: Chris, it works!   Great idea of storing the copied string first and closing that macro before running another.  It would be awesome if the run a macro multiple times to the end of the file could be accomplished via a keyboard shortcut that remembered your macro selection, and also closed itself, but maybe that will come later.

Answer (score 0):

Since the NPPExec script is so slow, here is another pure Notepad++ solution:

Do a regular expression find/replace like this:

- Open Replace Dialog
- **Find What:** `(PO (\d{10})[^\r\n]+\R(.*\2\R)*+)([^\r\n]+)(\R)`
- **Replace With:** `\1\4,\2\5`
- check **regular expression**
- click Replace or Replace All
- Keep clicking Replace All (or hold ALT-A pressed) until no more replacements are made (status bar of the find dialog will tell you)
- manually append `,ORDER_NUMBER` to the first line

One prerequisite is that the last line has a linebreak at its end, that means you have to add a missing linebreak manually in the last line or you need to insert the PO manually.

Comment: Hi Lars, thanks very much for this Regex suggestion.  It finds a find and replace only on the first line, but I will take some of your regex and be able to apply it elsewhere!